# autorelease with creating UIImage in ImageContext

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage

I am drawing into an ImageContext inside of an autorelease pool to control my memory footprint and from the inside of the autorelease pool I return the image. I had a crash in this call and I was wondering if it was caused by the image getting released in the autorelease pool before it is used by the calling function. Here is my code:

```
-( UIImage *)   imageRepFromShapes
{
    CGRect sheetDisplayView = [ UIScreen mainScreen ].bounds;


    @autoreleasepool {

        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions( boundingRect_m.size, NO, 0.0 );

        CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
        UIGraphicsPushContext(context);
        for ( Shape *shape in arryOfShapes ) {
            [ shape drawShape ];
        }
        UIGraphicsPopContext();

        UIImage     *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
        return image;
    }
}
```

The other question is do I need the UIGraphicsPushContext and UIGraphicsPopContext in this call and are they in the right place. 
I would appreciate clarification on this point.
With thanks

Reza

Comment: Please post your crash log, thanks.

Comment: it is one of those cases that happens very infrequently, in fact only once, and as I had zombie enabled in the development scheme, it just stopped in the call. That is why I am not sure if it is the call or something else. As I have zombie enabled, I expected that if it was a bug, it should always stop in the call, but it does not

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Move the `return` outside of the autorelease pool to make sure your image isn't thrown out. Do one of the following:

**ARC**

```
UIImage *image = nil;
@autoreleasepool {
    // ...
    image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
}
return image;
```

**non-ARC**

```
UIImage *image = nil;
@autoreleasepool {
    // ...
    image = [UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext() retain];
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
}
return [image autorelease];
```